# Can't connect my python script to SQL database that's on VM

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm using VirtualBox as my VM, and on it I have SQL server, and my python script runs on local host.

My connection string looks like this `engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://'+username+':'+password+'@127.0.0.1:1433/'+database+'?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')`

I'm getting "Data source name not found and default driver not specified" error.
I've tried a lot of stuff, and I can't make it work still.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in database drivers. I worked on a pc with SQL Server Native Client 11.0 driver, but I didn't have it on the pc where I was deploying the script and on which the VM was on.

Answer (score 0):

If you running Python script on System
The pythons script gets connected to localhost server of the system not Virtual Box

Comment: No, my script is on local, and DB is on VM

Comment: Sorry for mistake @LosProgramer. The python script on local system gets connected to localhost server on system not the virtual box. Try to run the python script in virtual box itself or try to run sql server in system.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but my script has to be on local and my DB on VM.